# How to fix "No such file or directory" library error? I am using Mingw-w64 compiler and Netbeans IDE

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I want to create a a text based interface (TUI) software. I found FTXUI library in GitHub and want to use it, so I downloaded it to my computer. The project repository structure is:

```
FTXUI-master
├───.github
├───doc
├───examples
│   ├───component
│   ├───dom
│   ├───html
│   └───util
├───include
│   └───ftxui
│       ├───component
│       ├───dom
│       ├───screen
│       └───util
├───other
└───src
    └───ftxui
        ├───component
        ├───dom
        └───screen
```

I am using Netbeans 8.2 RC and Mingw-w64 compiler, first I tried to add the includes and the sources in Netbeans adding the "include" and
"src" from FTXUI to the include and source file paths in Netbeans, like this:

```
CppApplication
│
│
├───HeaderFiles
│   └include
│    └───ftxui
│        ├───component
│        ├───dom
│        ├───screen
│        └───util
│
├───SourceFiles
│    └──main.cpp
│    └src
│     └───ftxui
│         ├───component
│         ├───dom
│         ├───screen
│         └───util
├───TestFiles
└───ImportantFiles
```

The main.cpp file content is:

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include "ftxui/dom/elements.hpp"
#include "ftxui/screen/screen.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  using namespace ftxui;

  // Define the document
  Element document =
    hbox({
      text(L"left")   | border,
      text(L"middle") | border | flex,
      text(L"right")  | border,
    });
 
  auto screen = Screen::Create(
    Dimension::Full(),       // Width
    Dimension::Fit(document) // Height
  );
  Render(screen, document);
  std::cout << screen.ToString() << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

The output I got was:

```
cd 'C:\Users\CurrentUser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_2'
C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f/checkbox.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f/checkbox.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f/checkbox.o ../../../Desktop/FTXUI-master/FTXUI-master/src/ftxui/component/checkbox.cpp
../../../Desktop/FTXUI-master/FTXUI-master/src/ftxui/component/checkbox.cpp:5:10: fatal error: ftxui/component/checkbox.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "ftxui/component/checkbox.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f/checkbox.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because your g++ command line has no option to add any directory to the header search path. So the preprocessor will look for your header files (between quotes) only in the directory of the current compiled file and some pre-configured folders. To add a director to the search path an option like -Idir should be used( it is the most commonly used ).
With Netbeans, you can add a directory in:
Option->C/C++->Code Assistance-> C Compiler   for gcc.
Option->C/C++->Code Assistance-> C++ Compiler for g++.

Comment: Thank you. I already try it, but it seems is the relative path declaration inside the library files.

Comment: Try running the g++ command line by adding -Ixxx/CppApplication/HeaderFiles/include. If is compiles you have to force the ide to add this include path.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an include directory in some non-standard location you have to tell NetBeans about that:

- Right-click on the project name in the `Projects` pane.
- Left-click on the `Properties` line in the drop-down menu (bottom line). The `Properties` pop-up window with a lot of settings for your project will come up.
- Choose `Build/C++ Compiler` in the left pane. All the compilation settings will show up.
- Find the line `Include Directories` (the top line). You can add any non-standard include directory to your project using the directory chooser - `...` on this line.
- Don't forget to click `OK` when you are done.

This pop-up window looks like this:

[image: Properties]